# Spring Boot Security: Exception handling with custom authentication filters

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot + Spring Security (java config).
My question is the old one, but all info which I've found is partially outdated and mostly contains xml-config (which difficult or even impossible to adapt some time)

I'm trying to do stateless authentication with a token (which doesn't stored on server side). Long story short - it is a simple analogue for JSON Web Tokens authentication format.
I'm using two custom filters before default one:

- TokenizedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter which creates token after 
  successful authentication on entry point ("/myApp/login")
- TokenAuthenticationFilter which tries to authenticate the user using token (if provided) for all restricted URLs.

I do not understand how properly handle custom exceptions(with custom message or redirect) if I want some...
Exceptions in filters are not relevant to exceptions in controllers, so they will not be handled by same handlers...

If I've understood right, I can not use

```
.formLogin()

                .defaultSuccessUrl("...")
                .failureUrl("...")
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(myAthenticationFailureHandler)
```

to customize exceptions, because I use custom filters...
So what the way to do it?

My config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()  .anonymous()

        .and()  .authorizeRequests()                      
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                ...
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()                    
        .and()                    
                .addFilterBefore(new TokenizedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter("/login",...), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)                      
                .addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(...), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

We can set AuthenticationSuccessHandler and AuthenticationFailureHandler in your custom filter as well.

Well in your case,

```
// Constructor of TokenizedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter class
public TokenizedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(String path, AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
    setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
    setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
}
```

Now to use these handlers just invoke `onAuthenticationSuccess()` or `onAuthenticationFailure()` methods.

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                          FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    getSuccessHandler().onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
}

@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                            AuthenticationException failed)
          throws IOException, ServletException {

    getFailureHandler().onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, failed);
}
```

You can create your custom authentication handler classes to handle the success or failure cases. For example,

```
public class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                      Authentication authentication)
          throws IOException, ServletException {

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    // Do your stuff, eg. Set token in response header, etc.
  }
}
```

Now for handling the exception,

```
public class LoginFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                      AuthenticationException e)
          throws IOException, ServletException {

    String errorMessage = ExceptionUtils.getMessage(e);

    sendError(httpServletResponse, HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, errorMessage, e);
  }


  private void sendError(HttpServletResponse response, int code, String message, Exception e) throws IOException {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

    Response<String> exceptionResponse =
            new Response<>(Response.STATUES_FAILURE, message, ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));

    exceptionResponse.send(response, code);
  }
}
```

My custom response class to generate desired JSON response,

```
public class Response<T> {

  public static final String STATUES_SUCCESS = "success";
  public static final String STATUES_FAILURE = "failure";

  private String status;
  private String message;
  private T data;

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Response.class);

  public Response(String status, String message, T data) {
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
    this.data = data;
  }

  public String getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public T getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public String toJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    try {
      return ow.writeValueAsString(this);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
      throw e;
    }
  }

  public void send(HttpServletResponse response, int code) throws IOException {
    response.setStatus(code);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    String errorMessage;

    errorMessage = toJson();

    response.getWriter().println(errorMessage);
    response.getWriter().flush();
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This will send one general error message on failure. How to send different error messages based on different cases